# How to avoid bloated constructor

Tags: php, laravel

Is there anyway to avoid passing too much paramaters on constructor. Like I'll just register my class in some service provider and it will automatically inject it in my class

**IssueController.php**

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->oProjectLogic = new ProjectLogic(new LibJIRA(), new LibJqlBuilder(), new ProjectModel());
        $aModels = [new InspectionModel(), new LinkStoryModel(), new ProjectModel(), new UserModel()];
        $this->oIssueLogic = new IssueLogic(new LibJIRA(), new LibJqlBuilder(), $this->oProjectLogic, ...$aModels);
    }
```

**IssueLogic.php**

```
    public function __construct(LibJIRA $oJiraLibrary, LibJqlBuilder $oBuilderLibrary, $oProjectLogic, $oInspectionModel, $oLinkStoryModel, $oProjectModel, $oUserModel)
    {
        $this->oJiraLibrary = $oJiraLibrary;
        $this->oBuilder = $oBuilderLibrary;
        $this->oInspectionModel = $oInspectionModel;
        $this->oLinkStoryModel = $oLinkStoryModel;
        $this->oProjectModel = $oProjectModel;
        $this->oProjectLogic = $oProjectLogic;
        $this->oUserModel = $oUserModel;
    }
```

Comment: There are a lot of dependency injection libraries out there.  [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/) and [Pimple](https://pimple.symfony.com/) come to mind.

Comment: or the IoC container that comes with Laravel itself (being the Application container)